# How can I delete a file pointed to by a FILE* in C?

Tags: c, file-io

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "Hello, World!\n");

    // remove("temp.txt");  this requires the filename as an argument
    // removefile(fp);      <--- is something like this possible?

    return 0;
}
```

The remove function ([defined in stdio.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove/)) takes the file name as a parameter, but not the file pointer itself.

Is there some function in the C standard libraries that does file deletion, and takes file pointer as the arguement?

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe there's any way to do this, because a FILE* may not necessarily correspond to a file in the filesystem at all (For example, stdin and stdout).

And in filesystems that support hard links, there can be multiple paths referring to the same underlying file, which one would you want it to remove?

Answer (score 7):

You may want to use the 'FILE * tmpfile(void)' function from stdlib.

from the man:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The tmpfile() function shall create a
>   temporary file and open a
>   corresponding stream. The file shall
>   be automatically deleted when all
>   references to the file are closed. The
>   file is opened as in fopen() for
>   update (w+).
>
> In some implementations, a permanent
>   file may be left behind if the process
>   calling tmpfile() is killed while  it 
>   is processing a call to tmpfile().
>
> An error message may be written to
>   standard error if the stream cannot be
>   opened.

Comment: How this mechanism work inside (i mean implementation of tmpfile method)?

Comment: You always have the source codes of std-lib to view ... on posix, one can open a file, and unlink immediately, and the open file will continue to be usable.  I wonder how it works on Windwows!
Also .. the point that file may be left in case of process is kill abruptly .. seems to imply atexit() at work

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. And `FILE` struct doesn't include filename inside it. So best option is to have structure that will both hold pointer to `FILE` and to `char*` with name

Answer (score 1):

You closed pointer, then her value was freed, how you imagine delete file by this handle?

Comment: @Audrey: `Closes the file associated with the stream and disassociates it.`

Comment: corret, it's not set to null. It's a pointing to freed memory, and potential for a segv/gpf. In fact, you should add a 'fp = 0' line just after the fclose().

Comment: can I do the same before closing the file handle?

Comment: @Lazer: no, because you can write a wrapper for operating files function, to save filename path while fopen is calling by wrapper, and if you call fclose via wrapper, file was be fclose and deleted by char* previously saved.