# Deleting a file using a FILE *

Tags: c, file, delete-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I delete a file pointed to by a FILE* in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657886/how-can-i-delete-a-file-pointed-to-by-a-file-in-c)

I want to delete a file at the end of a **C** program, by which point the filename has been long forgotten. It would be nice if I could just use the FILE * to delete it directly or find the filename and then use remove()... rather than having to memorize the filename for this.

Does anybody know of any ways in which this could be achieved? I am on a Windows system, but I need to maintain portability so can't use any OS specific stuff.

Comment: 'Forgotten'?? :) Create a variable to remember it then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> nice if I could just use the FILE * to delete it directly or find the
>   filename and then use remove()... rather than having to memorize the
>   filename for this

There's no way to retrieve the file name from a `FILE *`. A `FILE *` isn't necessarily a real file; just think of `popen(3)` for example.

Comment: +1 because file descriptors don't always map to files :)  deleting a file is a filesystem operation, not a general IO operation.

Comment: I guess I'll have to just memorize the filename then. Thought the program would be neater without, but nevermind.

Comment: @Luke There are always *ways*, obtaining the HANDLE from the FILE * and then obtaining the name from the HANDLE etc. But the cleanest and easiest way is to store the name somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a portable way, but there is a Linux version (which might work on other unices) and a Windows version:

Linux: a `readlink()` on `sprintf("/proc/self/fd/%d",fd)` should work

Windows:  `GetFileInformationByHandleEx()` will give you the name as part of a struct (Search MSDN, don't have the details in my head)

Answer (score 1):

E.g

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void endproc(void){
    remove("removeFile.dat");
}

int main(){
    atexit(endproc);
    return 0;
}
```